# Problem with some keys when editing HTML in wordpress "text" editor

Tags: editor, html-editor

My wordpress 4.9 editor for posts has two editor views

- Visual
- Text

I am mostly using the text view and often adding shortcuts.  Sometimes I directly add HTML5 code, e.g. for tables.  However, these following keys stop responding when I do so and surrounded by HTML tags:

- left arrow
- right arrow
- home keys (go to line start)
- end key (to to line end)

Backspace sometimes works correctly, but sometimes jumps to an unexpected place in the line to erase a character.

To navigate within a line I have to first move up or down, and then reenter the line using the mouse to select position.

- **Is this behavior normal?  Is there some logic behind it I don't
  understand?**
- **Although my editor doesn't have an HTML view, I have seen
  references to an HTML view, e.g. [on this wordpress support
  page](https://en.support.wordpress.com/editors/).  Can I somehow enable this view option and would it solve my problem?**

Answer (score 1):

The "Text" editor was used to be called "HTML" which is probably the source of the references you find. (it is actually neither, but for sure it is not an HTML editor per-se).

As for your problems, this sounds more like a call to replace your keyboard, but assuming it is not an hardware issue you will need to deactivate plugins to find out which one is causing it (and switch themes to a vanilla theme if it will not be a plugin).

Comment: That information about "Text Editor" being the new name for "HTML Editor" makes thing clear,, and I agree it's not much of an editor for HTML.  Now I'm doing the HTML bits in emacs editor, and pasting into wordpress later. I guess it is not hardware because it only happens in wordpress when editing HTML, not any other time, not even in wordpress editing plain text.
I only use plugins I need, and I don't want to fix them and manage keeping a separate fix across plugin upgrades.